# Clustered index consideration in regards to distinct valus and large result sets and a single vertical table for auditing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design, indexing

I've been researching best practices for creating clustered indexes and I'm just trying to totally understand these two suggestions that's listed with pretty much every BLOG or article on the matter

- Columns that contain a large number of distinct values.
- Queries that return large result sets.

These seem to be slightly contrary or I'm guessing maybe it just depends on how you're accessing the table.. Or my interpretation of what "large result sets"  mean is wrong....

Unless you're doing range queries over the clustered column it seems like you typically won't be getting large result sets that matter. So in cases where SQL Server defaults the clustered indexes on the PK you're rarely going to fulfill the large result set suggestion but of course it does the large number of distinct values..

To give the question a little more context. This quetion stems from a vertical auditing table we have that has a column for TABLE.... Every single query that's written against this table has a

```
WHERE TABLE = 'TABLENAME'
```

But the TableName is highly non distinct... Each result set of tablenames is rather large which seems to fulfill that second conditon but it's definitely not largerly unique.... Which means all that other stuff happens with having to add the 4 byte Uniquifer (sp?) which makes the table a lot larger etc...

This situation has come up a few times for me when I've come upon DBs that have say all the contact or some accounts normalized into a single table and they are only separated by a TYPE parameter. Which is on every query....

In the case of the audit table the queries are typically not that exciting either they are just sorted by date modified, sometimes filtered by column, user that made the change etc...

My other thought with this auditing scenario was to just make the auditing table a HEAP so that inserting is fast so there's not contention between tables being audited and then to generate indexed views over the data ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Index design is just as much art as it is science.

There are many things to consider, including:

- How the table will be accessed most often: mostly inserts? any updates? more SELECTs than DML statements? Any audit table will likely have mostly inserts, no updates, rarely deletes unless there is a time-limit on the data, and some SELECTs.
- For Clustered indexes, keep in mind that the data in each column of the clustered index will be copied into each non-clustered index (though not for `UNIQUE` indexes, I believe). This is helpful as those values are available to queries using the non-clustered index for covering, etc. But it also means that the physical space taken up by the non-clustered indexes will be that much larger.
- Clustered indexes *generally* should either be declared with the `UNIQUE` keyword or be the Primary Key (though there are exceptions, of course). A non-unique clustered index will have a hidden 4-byte field called a uniqueifier that is required to make each row with a non-unique key value addressable, and is just wasted space given that the order of your rows within the non-unique groupings is not apparently obvious so trying to narrow down to a single row is still a range.
- As is mentioned everywhere, the clustered index is the physical ordering of the data so you want to cater to what needs the best I/O. This relates also to the point directly above where non-unique clustered indexes have an order but if the data is truly non-unique (as opposed to unique data but missing the UNIQUE keyword when the index was created) then you miss out on a lot of the benefit of having the data physically ordered.
- Regardless of any information or theory, TEST TEST TEST. There are many more factors involved that pertain to your specific situation.

So, you mentioned having a `Date` field as well as the `TableName`. If the combination of the Date and TableName is unique then those should be used as a composite key on a PK or UNIQUE CLUSTERED index. If they are not then find another field that creates the uniqueness, such as `UserIDModified`.

While most recommendations are to have the most unique field as the first one (due to statistics being only on the first field), this doesn't hold true for all situations. Given that all of your queries are by `TableName`, I would opt for putting that field first to make use of the physical ordering of the data. This way SQL Server can read more relevant data per read without having to seek to other locations on disk. You would likely also being ordering on the `Date` so I would put that field second. Putting `TableName` first will cause higher fragmentation across INSERTs than putting the `Date` first, but upon an index rebuild the data access will be faster as the data is already both grouped ( `TableName` ) and ordered ( `Date` ) as the queries expect. If you put `Date` first then the data is still ordered properly but the rows needed to satisfy the query are likely spread out across the datafile(s) which would require more I/O to get. AND, more data pages to satisfy the same query means more pages in the Buffer Pool, potentially pushing out other pages and reducing Page Life Expectancy (PLE). Also, you would then really need to inculde the `Date` field in all queries as any queries using only `TableName` (and possibly other filters but NOT using the `Date` field) will have to scan the clustered index or force you to create a nonclustered index with `TableName` being first.

I would be weary of the Heap plus Indexed View model. Yes, it might be optimized for the inserts but the system still needs to maintain the data in the indexed view across all DML statements against the heap. Again you would need to test, but I don't see that being materially better than a good choice of fields for a clustered index on the audit table.

Comment: Great Answer :-)

I'm curious if the performance gain of having Table first is enough to justify the other work involved with staying on top of rebuilding indexes. Especially being an audit table if anything goes wrong with the maintenance of that table and it experiences high fragmentation the whole system could suffer since every transaction has to insert values into that table...

Also I'm curious if this scenario is kind of excessive normalization and the tablenames should just be partitioned out..

TEST TEST TEST TEST right :-)

Comment: +1 great answer - covers all the major points (clustering key is included in **all** non-clustered indices as well and thus should be **narrow, static, unique** and - if possible - ever-increasing!)

Comment: @PureWeen, if you have Enterprise Edition then you can do an online rebuild so that will not be an issue. And some would argue that the situation that causes fragmentation benefits from avoiding the lesser-known problem of a "hotspot" which can happen when many INSERTs happen on the same data page. I am not sure that partitioning is valid in this case as it is mainly intended to increase bulk loading performance. I am just telling you what my experience has been on 100 million+ row tables with hundreds of transactions per second. And maybe you will just need a stats update and not a rebuild.

Comment: @marc_s, thanks :). Good point about the "static". I generally agree about the ever increasing, but as I just mentioned in my comment to PureWeen, that "sometimes" leads to a hot-spot issue. But I have no idea how often that happens.

Comment: @srutzky: yes, it will lead to a hot-spot - and that's a **good thing!** After all: if you have a hot spot of activity, there's pretty much a guarantee that page (or those pages) will stay in SQL Server cache memory! Since v7.0, a hotspot is really not a "bad" thing anymore (it used to be, in earlier versions)

Comment: @marc_s, interesting. I could have sworn that I have read some recent blogs by some MVPs talking about them being a bad thing as recently as v 2008. I will have to do more research.

Comment: Yea same... a lot of good points to launch into my next stage of research into indexing magic :-) Thanks everyone!!